# Login error trying to make a pull request

Tags: git

I am trying to commit a branch to a repo I don't own in order to make a pull request.

I checked out a new branch(git checkout -b feature-branch) and when I try to  `git push origin`, it asks me for my username and password. Do I need permissions to commit branches to a repo I don't own? What is the proper procedure for making pull requests on a repo you don't have ownership to?

Comment: Check the documentation https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must fork the repository first, then pushing changes.
this guide  will help you: https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/